# How to redirect from a button click inside WKWebview and to go back to the iOS application using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, wkwebview

I am developing a native iOS application . On a button click I am loading a website app inside the `WKWebview`. Inside the web view after logging in with username and password the following permission screen comes to us which has "Allow" and "Deny" button.

What I want is when pressing on the "Allow" button the current screen should get dismissed and redirect back to my application. Similarly with the "Deny" button . After so much of research I found the following Swift code for the `WKWebviewDelegate`:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    // here we handle internally the callback url and call method that call handleOpenURL (not app scheme used)
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.host == "localhost" , url.path == "/square-oauth-callback" {


        print(url)
        print(url.valueOf("code"))
        //decisionHandler(.cancel)

        /*  Dismiss your view controller as normal
            And proceed with OAuth authorization code
            The code you receive here is not the auth token; For auth token you have to make another api call with the code that you received here and you can procced further
         */

        /*
            Auth Process Flow: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/how-it-works#oauth-access-token-management

            Obtain Auth Token: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/oauth-api/obtain-token
         */

    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Am I correct in my approach?
If yes can someone please tell the Objective-C alternative of the above code? Sorry for the case as I recently started my career using Swift and I have very little knowledge about Objective-C. If no, can someone suggest me the correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same delegate method can be used in objective-C also:

```
    - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```

Objective-C conversion of above code:

```
  - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
        if ([navigationAction.request.URL isEqual:@"localhost"] && [navigationAction.request.URL.path isEqual:@"/square-oauth-callback"]) {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
            NSLog(@"URL:%@",navigationAction.request.URL);
        }
        else
        {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
        }
}
```

Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview?language=objc

Comment: yes thanks can you please modify the whole code into objective c?